# `git push -u` with non-standard `remote.origin.fetch` config doesn't actually set up a tracking branch

Tags: git

I use a git monorepo shared with 100s of engineers. The convention is that everyone prefixes their branches to not collide with the others. In order to avoid overfetching, I have `.git/config` configured to only fetch a shared `master` + my own `jakub/*` branches:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:org/repo.git
    # fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  # Commented out, I don't want all branches
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/jakub/*:refs/remotes/origin/jakub/*
```

Sporadically though, I create (usually by accident, but not always) an unprefixed branch. When I `git push -u` it, git tells that it's tracking `origin/foobar`:

```
git checkout -b foobar
git push -u origin foobar
...
branch 'foobar' set up to track 'origin/foobar'.
```

But actually this tracking branch is not there:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u}
fatal: upstream branch 'refs/heads/foobar' not stored as a remote-tracking branch
```

I figured I can fix it by amending my fetch config:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/foobar:refs/remotes/origin/foobar'
```

This itself is not enough though:

```
git status
Your branch is based on 'origin/foobar', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

I need to fetch to really get the tracking branch:

```
# git fetch
# git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u}
origin/foobar

# git status
On branch foobar
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/foobar'.
```

**My question is: Is the git behavior of `git push -u` correct in this case when I try to push to a branch that is not in fetch config? Should it:**

- Print a warning message?
- Automatically update fetch config (before pushing)?

The other issue though is:

If I add the tracking branch manually

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/foobar:refs/remotes/origin/foobar'
```

but then someone else deletes `origin/foobar`, when I `git fetch`, it will fail because `origin/foobar` does not exist.

Is there a good solution for this? Like, making the fetch spec for `foobar` optional?